# How to Format ISO-8601 in Java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to change from standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format `2014-09-11T21:28:29.429209Z` into a nice MMM d yyyy hh:mm z format, however my current code is failing.

```
public void setCreatedAt( String dateTime ) {

    LocalDate newDateTime = LocalDate.parse(dateTime);

    try {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy hh:mm a z");
        createdAt = newDateTime.format(format); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

I am receiving the time and date from an api.

Comment: @RaminOmrani the "z" in 2014-09-11T21:28:29.429209Z stands for UTC.

Comment: did you tried joda time API for it ??

Comment: @Bhupi there is no reason to switch to joda time to solve this problem. As a matter of fact, most likely you are going to be presented with the same choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `java.time.LocalDate` is "a date without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03" so there is not enough information there. Use `java.time.ZonedDateTime` instead.

Also, swallowing exceptions like that makes it much harder to troubleshoot. When you don't intend to handle an exception either don't catch it at all, catch and re-throw it wrapped in a RuntimeException or at the very least log it (`e.printStackTrace()` or similar) .

Comment: it worked! Thank you! I definitely need to work on the exceptions. Thank you for the tip! :)

Comment: Also note that `LocalDate` is not able to hold the time components, only the date components.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2014-09-11T21:28:29.429209Z" )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) )
       .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d uuuu hh:mm a z" , Locale.US ) )
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/ACZb2A).

## Details

The [Answer by Jakber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31299227/642706) will work technically but is misleading.

## `ZonedDateTime` is for time zones

A [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) is meant to have an assigned time zone such as `America/Montreal` or `Pacific/Auckland`.

But this input string lacks a time zone. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC, or in other words, an offset-from-UTC of zero hours, `+00:00`.

A time zone is a historical collection of offsets for a particular region with rules for upcoming changes to the offset for anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

## `Instant`

The input string is better parsed as an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) which represents a moment on the timeline always in UTC. This class directly parses such strings in that particular standard ISO 8601 format, so no need for formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2014-09-11T21:28:29.429209Z" );
```

## Adjust into time zone

You can adjust into a time zone to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

## Generating string

To generate a string in the same format as input, simply call `Instant::toString()`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

For your custom format using the wall-clock time of a region, use `DateTimeFormatter` with your custom formatting pattern. And your `ZonedDateTime`. As a good habit, always specify the desired Locale used for the human language in translation and cultural norms in formatting.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d uuuu hh:mm a z" , Locale.US );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setCreatedAt(String dateTime) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfSource = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
    SimpleDateFormat sdfTarget = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy hh:mm a z", Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Date date = sdfSource.parse(dateTime);
        String createdAt = sdfTarget.format(date);
        Log.e(TAG, "setCreatedAt: createdAt " + createdAt);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Which the OP is even already using.